# What is radz.stackoverflow.com, how do you use it for linking to books?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I see people linking to Amazon via a radz.stackoverflow.com link.

What is this all about?  I use direct links to Amazon. Does this link generate affiliate purchases for the stackexchange network if someone buys the book through the link?  Or is it just a URL shortening service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's for our affiliate links, when you post a link to amazon it will be converted to an SO Affiliate link. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

Answer (score 5):

For written sf (excluding comics), a better link for books and stories is the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database (ISFDB)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi). There are pages for authors, works and publications. Of course, when there's a Wikipedia page, that's a good alternative.

Comment: I assume the point of making it an SO Affiliate link means should you decide to buy it after having been redirected to Amazon, SO gets some kick back.