# Is there a citation convention for this site?

Tags: discussion, citations

The answers for certain book-related questions on this site often lack citations for the original source. I want to improve that in my answers. Is there a convention already established for what info to include when referencing a book passage?

I realize that this site is global so page numbers may not be appropriate, but some books like *Game of Thrones* do not contain numbered chapters so I am unsure how to point someone to an appropriate passage.

Comment: Adding these in across the site for existing answers/questions would be a fantastic gift to the community if anyone is looking to give one.

Answer (score 5):

[We've discussed linking to books before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/what-is-the-convention-for-linking-to-books), but as far as I can remember we haven't touched on how to cite a passage. On the topic of citing books, I would like to recommend two things:

- Use the full name of the author and the full title of the work the first time you cite a work in a post (e.g. write “*A Song of Ice and Fire* by George R. R. Martin” once, and only then abbreviations such as ASoIaF and GRRM).
- Provide a link for people who'd like more information about the work. I prefer [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) if applicable, and [IMDB](http://imdb.com/) or [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) as second choices.

For specific passages, when there aren't any chapter numbers, my best suggestion is:

- Give the page number and the total number of pages for your edition, e.g. “on page 42/224”.
- Quote the first sentence of the first paragraph you're referring to. Quoting a passage helps people who have the book in a searchable electronic form (and that's everyone if the sentence can be found in Google Books or elsewhere on the web). Making it specifically the beginning of a paragraph helps people who're trying to locate the passage visually in a printed book.
- Search the passage on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/). This sometimes gives you a link to the passage in context. Depending on what agreement Google has with the publisher, you might be find nothing at all, or just a few lines, or the surrounding page, or be able to browse around the passage.
- Explain how to find the passage in relation with memorable events. (E.g. “after the death of Alice, the first time the viewpoint returns to Bob”.)

Comment: [example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/4662/2)

Answer (score 0):

Other than linking to online documents there is no official citation system in the Stack network, unlike wikipedia.  You can however use some the [limited html tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed) to approximate footer notes and what not.

For instance,  "Johnny said this"<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>Awesome book by that one guy.</sub>

I did this using the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags for sub and super text.

Sorry if this doesn't really answer the original question well.